# Nested Cursors in MYSQL, cursor not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have created an SP in MYSQL to get values by date, by the sensor. My SP executes the inner cursor correctly but the outer cursor(1st cursor) is not executed. i.e. I only get 1 day of data, dateTable has a week's data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Analysis`()
BEGIN
declare v_date datetime;
declare v_sensor varchar(50);
DECLARE datecursHandler,sensorCursHandler BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

Block1: BEGIN 
declare datecursor CURSOR for 
select  distinct date from dateTable;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET datecursHandler = TRUE;

Open datecursor;
datecurs: loop

FETCH datecursor into date;
IF datecursHandler THEN
        CLOSE datecursor;
        LEAVE datecurs;
END IF;

        Block2: BEGIN 

        declare sensorCursor CURSOR for
        select distinct sensor from sensorTable ;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET sensorcur = TRUE;

        Open sensorCursor;
        senscurs: loop
        FETCH  sensorCursor into sensor;

        IF sensorcur THEN
                SET sensorcur = False;
                CLOSE sensorCursor;
                LEAVE senscurs;
                END IF;

        Insert into temptable(
        sensorValue,
        DateID,
        TimeID, 
        TotalCount,
        TotalDistinctCount
        )
        SELECT 
            sensor AS sensorValue,
            DATE_FORMAT(firstdate, '%Y%m%d') AS DateID,
            HOUR(firstdate) + 1 AS TimeID,
            COUNT(*) AS totalcount,
            COUNT(DISTINCT sensor) AS sensordistinctcount
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                    sensor AS sensor,
                    first_seen AS DeviceFirstSeen,
                    last_seen AS DeviceLastSeen,
                    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(first_seen), '%Y/%m/%d %k:%i:%s.%f') AS firstdate,
                    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_seen), '%Y/%m/%d %k:%i:%s.%f') AS lastdate,          
            FROM
                sensorTable
            INNER JOIN sensorTable2 ON sensorTable.ID = sensorTable2.ID
            WHERE sensorTable.DeviceFirstSeen BETWEEN date_format(date_sub(date,interval 1 day),'%Y-%m-%d 15:00:00') AND date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d 14:59:59')) a
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(firstdate, '%Y%m%d') , HOUR(firstdate) + 1;

        end loop Maccurs;


        END Block2;
END loop datecurs;
END Block1;
END
```

Can anyone please help me debug my code? I have researched but so far my code looks correct as per my research but doesn't work as expected.

**Required Output:
Get counts of all the sensors for each day each hour that is selected from dateTable.**

Comment: With all due respect, "doesn't work as expected" is not a very good description of your problem. What did you expect it to do? What does it do instead? Does it return an error? If so, what is the exact error message?

Comment: I see a typo in the IF datecursHandler. LEAVE datecurs should be LEAVE datecursor, right?

Comment: @MartijnVissers Nope, Leave datecurs is the name of the loop to exit.

Comment: Alright, my bad

Comment: @success-maharjan Add continue handler in block2 and if no records add the IF leave loop too.

Comment: @James, I added the handler in block 2 as well but still, it runs for a single day. Any more suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below procedure, Since the issue might be incorrect closing of cursor.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Analysis`()
BEGIN
declare v_date datetime;
declare v_sensor varchar(50);
DECLARE datecursHandler,sensorCursHandler BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

Block1: BEGIN 
declare datecursor CURSOR for 
select  distinct date from dateTable;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET datecursHandler = TRUE;

select  distinct date from dateTable; #what is the result set you are getting?

Open datecursor;
datecurs: loop

FETCH datecursor into v_date;
IF datecursHandler THEN
        LEAVE datecurs;
END IF;

        Block2: BEGIN 

        declare sensorCursor CURSOR for
        select distinct sensor from sensorTable ;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET sensorCursHandler = TRUE;

        Open sensorCursor;
        senscurs: loop
        FETCH  sensorCursor into v_sensor;

          IF sensorCursHandler THEN
    SET sensorCursHandler  = false;
       LEAVE senscurs;
          END IF;

        Insert into temptable(
        sensorValue,
        DateID,
        TimeID, 
        TotalCount,
        TotalDistinctCount
        )
        SELECT 
            sensor AS sensorValue,
            DATE_FORMAT(firstdate, '%Y%m%d') AS DateID,
            HOUR(firstdate) + 1 AS TimeID,
            COUNT(*) AS totalcount,
            COUNT(DISTINCT sensor) AS sensordistinctcount
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                    sensor AS sensor,
                    first_seen AS DeviceFirstSeen,
                    last_seen AS DeviceLastSeen,
                    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(first_seen), '%Y/%m/%d %k:%i:%s.%f') AS firstdate,
                    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_seen), '%Y/%m/%d %k:%i:%s.%f') AS lastdate,          
            FROM
                sensorTable
            INNER JOIN sensorTable2 ON sensorTable.ID = sensorTable2.ID
            WHERE sensorTable.DeviceFirstSeen BETWEEN date_format(date_sub(date,interval 1 day),'%Y-%m-%d 15:00:00') AND date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d 14:59:59')) a
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(firstdate, '%Y%m%d') , HOUR(firstdate) + 1;

        end loop senscurs;
        close sensorCursor;
        END Block2;

END loop datecurs;
close datecursor;
END Block1;
END
```

Comment: I updated my code with block2 handler as well as using different variable name. I am getting weird result of only 1 and 2 hours for A and B sensors for 1 day.

Comment: sorry please ignore my last comment on the weird resultset, it was my data issue. How do i make it work to run for multiple days?

Comment: I am still getting data only for 1 day. I have used the script you provided. The block 2 loop is alright looping to A and B sensors, but the block 1 loop of date is not working.

Comment: what is the distinct date output you received?

Comment: I have 7 dates in my date table and I get all the dates when selecting distinct dates. Tested by putting the query on the SP itself as well.

Comment: After "FETCH datecursor into v_date;" insert "select v_date;" then check what date is being parsed.

Comment: so the begin date is 2019-03-05 in my data, that data gets inserted into the table. After that the 2nd cursor is not used.

Comment: I added the select v_date and it shows the date after my begin date i.e. 2019-03-06

Comment: so how many times it displays the output? btw in which you are running the scripts? Workbench?

Comment: all the 7 dates that is available in the date table. YES, mysql Workbench

Comment: So it works... since what block 1 does is when you get date it executes block 2 again and again.

Comment: Hey @james, I was able to solve my problem by adding a line in the code you provided.  I have edited your code and marked as solution. Thanks for your help on my problem.